# Realm.io - How to update object?

Tags: android, realm

I am using 0.81.1 version of Realm. I have this class:

```
public class KanjiComp extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String character;
    private String strokes;
    private int frequency;

    public String getCharacter() {
        return character;
    }

    public void setCharacter(String character) {
        this.character = character;
    }

    public String getStrokes() {
        return strokes;
    }

    public void setStrokes(String strokes) {
        this.strokes = strokes;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }
}
```

For the first time, I create object like this:

```
    KanjiComp realmKanjiComp = realm.createObject(KanjiComp.class);
    realmKanjiComp.setCharacter(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("literal")));
    realmKanjiComp.setStrokes(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("strokes")));
    realmKanjiComp.setFrequency(0);
```

I want to increment frequency value. For this purpose I need method which helps me update frequency.

Realm documentation says this:

> Using primary keys makes it possible to use the createOrUpdate()
>   method, which will look for an existing object with this primary key,
>   an update it if it finds one; if none are found, it will create a new
>   object instead.

But I could not find createOrUpdate() method. All methods to work with JSON.
[image]

My full code looks like this:

```
        try {
            KanjiComp realmKanjiComp = realm.createObject(KanjiComp.class);
            character = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("literal"));
            realmKanjiComp.setCharacter(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("literal")));
            realmKanjiComp.setStrokes(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("strokes")));
            realmKanjiComp.setFrequency(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            RealmQuery<KanjiComp> query = realm.where(KanjiComp.class);
            query.equalTo("character", character);
            RealmResults<KanjiComp> rKanjiComp = query.findAll();
            KanjiComp oldKanjiComp = rKanjiComp.get(0);

            KanjiComp realmKanjiComp = realm.update(KanjiComp.class);//update is underlined
            realmKanjiComp.setCharacter(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("literal")));
            realmKanjiComp.setStrokes(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("strokes")));
            realmKanjiComp.setFrequency(oldKanjiComp.getFrequency()+1);
        }
```

So my question is, how to update value of my object? Is there any way to increment value of my object?

Comment: Try to wrap it in transaction. 
  realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                KanjiComp testObject = realm.createObject(KanjiComp.class);
                testObject.setValue(value);
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(testObject);
            }
        });

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
void createKanjiCompOrUpdateFrequency() {
    // This query is fast because "character" is an indexed field
    KanjiComp kanjoComp = realm.where(KanjiComp.class)
                               .equalTo("character", someValue)
                               .findFirst();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    if (kanjiComp == null) {
        KanjiComp kanjiComp = realm.createObject(KanjiComp.class);
        // set the fields here
    } else {
        kanjiComp.setFrequency(kanjiComp.getFrequency() + 1);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: what is the type of character field? ... I don't think we could save char filed in realm.. do you use `String` as a replacement for char?